# How to submit IIS created CSR to StartSSL certificate provider?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ssl

I'm in process of setting [IIS server](http://www.iis.net/) up with free [SSL certitificate](https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/) from [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/).

I'm new in this domain. StartSSL seems to be legit to me.

My question is regarding [point 7 on their website](https://www.startssl.com/?app=31)

The point says

> *Open the CSR that you created and submit it to your certificate provider.*

**How do I submit the CSR file to my provider? By email, fax or is there a dialogue** (which I'm unable to see) **in IIS to do so?**

Have anyone done setting up SSL certs for their web servers with StartSSL?

Comment: Have you already validated your identity? You;ll need to paste the CSR in an input window in the certificates wizard, but you will need to validate your personal identity and the domain on which you want to create the certificate first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example, StartSSL *is* your certificate provider.

While logged into StartSSL, use the "Certificate Wizard" to submit your certificate signing request (CSR).  You must have already validated your domain with them, which is to say, you went through the Validations Wizard and they've established that you have sufficient ownership of a domain to be requesting certs for it.

[image: StartSSL Certificates Wizard Screen 1]

Skip this step of the wizard since you've generated your own key and want to submit a CSR.

[image: StartSSL Certificates Wizard Screen 2]

Submitting a CSR is simply pasting the text into the box:

[image: StartSSL Certificates Wizard Screen 3]

And then follow the rest of the steps of the wizard, which are all pretty simple.

I've used StartSSL for a few years, they are legit, but their web site is not the most usable in some ways.  I think the instructions you link to are generic, perhaps taken from somewhere else, and that's why they don't clearly link into the StartSSL part of the process.

Comment: Will try your solution tomorrow *however* **The quality of your answer has compelled me to accept this as an answer.**

Comment: this leads me to a [new question](http://serverfault.com/questions/712942/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-using-text)